# Razer Blackwidow X Chroma Tournament Edition got broken after pouring isopropilic alcohol

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

I was cleaning my keyboard, and the idea of cleaning the insides of the switches pouring isopropilic alcohol onto them and pressing them multiple times came across my mind. I did it with every switch. Cost me like 2:30 hrs. I waited two days to let it dry in front of the window. Then I connected it and saw that some very specific keys like Y and N didn't work properly (registered only 6 of 10 keypresses). And then I realized that some keys lost their iconic click sound; they now sound kind of like brown.

What was my mistake? What did I do wrong? I saw people that clean their mechanical keyboards like this and got no problems.

Comment: Depending on the design of the keyboard it might start working after a longer period of time to dry. But, pouring liquid on it was a really bad idea. A keyboard is pretty much one of the worse things to pour liquid on. A lot will depend on how pure the alcohol was and the design of the switches. There are tight tolerances and places that will trap liquid for a long time. Chances are, it’s toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that I didn't find any good source mentioning the use of
isopropyl alcohol on keyboards.

I know that
Isopropyl alcohol is a solvent, so whether it causes damage depends on the materials
used for the construction of the keyboard.

I have looked for user reports, and while some have reported success, others
reported a destroyed keyboard.

An example is
[[help] I accidentally murdered my keyboard with rubbing alcohol](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/2cv62u/help_i_accidentally_murdered_my_keyboard_with/)
where the guy used 99% rubbing alcohol (which might however be different from
99% isopropyl alcohol).

In the post
[corsair k70 keycaps can i use alcohol to clean?](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/645902-corsair-k70-keycaps-can-i-use-alcohol-to-clean/),
the answer was "Don't use isopropyl alcohol. it can damage stuff".

In the post
[Safest concentration of Isopropyl alcohol to use for keyboard cleaning](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=90545.0)
the advice was never to use more than 50% concentration, obtained by buying
the 99% and adding water.

My conclusion is that while some people successfully used isopropyl alcohol
to clean their keyboard, your keyboard is one of those that it destroys.
I also note that most people that reported success only used the isopropyl alcohol
to clean around the switches or on the caps, but not for cleaning
below the cap. Most people recommended using soapy water for that.